# Binding to parent in relative aggregation binding

Tags: sapui5

I have my view bound like this to an oData model:

```
this.getView().bindElement({
   path: 'Entity(ID='1234')',
   model: 'odataModel',
   ...
});
```

The data would look like this:

```
{
    "ID": "1234",
    "TITLE": "dummy",
    "ITEMS": [
        {
            "ID": "1234",
            "POS": "1"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1234",
            "POS": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the XML view I have an items aggregation binding, bound relative to the parent.

```
            <List 
                items="{path: 'odataModel>ITEMS'}">
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <Text text={
                            parts: [{path: 'odataModel>POS'}, {path: 'to TITLE here'}],
                            formatter: '.format'
                        }/>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
```

Would it be possible to create a relative binding to the TITLE property for the Text control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

A) Add this property in the back end on the item level

OR

B) Create a navigation property from the Items to the parent entity and then adjust your binding to

```
{path: 'ToParentEntity/TITLE'}
```

Moreover, probably the header binding is wrong as it should have a leading slash

```
this.getView().bindElement({
   path: '/Entity(ID='1234')',
   model: 'odataModel'
});
```

Consider using the `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.createKey` method to get the `path` using variables before calling the `bindElement`.

Comment: I did use a to parent association for the display mode which works fine, but I needed it for editing as well, so the binding is updated and the formatter function executed on every pending change, which wouldn't work since the TITLE property would be changed on the parent directly, so with a different context. As a solution, I just keep the changes of that property from the oData model in sync with a JSON model and use that in the binding.

Comment: And indeed, the header is missing the slash, I just quickly wrote the code as mockup, it's not actually used. I didn't know about the createKey method, I shall start using that from now on, is there an equivalent for v4 or can that be used for v4 as well since the syntax in compatible?